# Is there a short way to check whether the user input ends with one of the elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ends-with

Is there a short way to find out whether the user input **ends with** (`endsWith()`) one of the elements in an array? I would like to check if the user input ends with one of the following suffixes: "ss", "ll", "tt". If the user input ends with one of those suffixes, the code should alert a message saying "condition met", otherwise it should alert "condition failed". I can do it using simple if statements as shown in the following code:

```js
    var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
   

    function findingSuffixes(){

    if(inp.value.endsWith('ss') || inp.value.endsWith('tt') || inp.value.endsWith('ll')){
    alert('condition met')
    } else {
    alert('condition failed')
    }
    
    }
```

```html
    <p>Enter a word:</p>
    <input type="text" id="inp">
    <button onclick="findingSuffixes()">Find out</button>
```

But this is a bit circuitous.

I tried to approach it from a different angle. I created an array and stored the suffixes in it and then looped through that array and passed the **array[i]** into the `endsWith` method as an argument, but it didn't work as expected.

```js
    var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
    suffixes = ["ss", "tt", "ll"];



    function findingSuffixes(){


    for(var i=0; i < suffixes.length; i++){

    if(inp.value.endsWith(suffixes[i])){
    alert("condition Met")
    } else {
    alert("condition failed")
    }
    
    } 
   
    
    }
```

```html
    <p>Enter a word:</p>
    <input type="text" id="inp">
    <button onclick="findingSuffixes()">Find out</button>
```

**TL'DR:** Is there a short way to check whether the user input ends with one of the elements in an array?

Comment: do you have alway two characters? do you want to know which one matches?

Comment: @NinaScholz: No, not always two characters. For my project, I have five characters at the end, but for the sake of ease and clarity, I just chose 2 in this question. I want to know if the user input ends with *any* of the array elements.

Comment: why not use a regular expression?

Comment: Use `suffixes.some()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it issues the `alert` while still in the loop. You only want it to declare "met" or "failed" when it knows for sure. I adjusted the code to show how this can be done.  I use `break` to exit the loop once we meet the condition since there is no need to look further.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var suffixes = ["ss", "tt", "ll"];

function findingSuffixes(){
  var msg = "condition failed";
  for(const suffix of suffixes){
    if (inp.value.endsWith(suffix)){
      msg = "condition Met";
      break;  // no need to continue in the loop
    } 
  } 
  alert(msg);
}
```

```html
<p>Enter a word:</p>
    <input type="text" id="inp">
    <button onclick="findingSuffixes()">Find out</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [regular experssion](https://regex101.com/r/gmCg4Q/1) and test the string aginst this expression.

```
/(ll|ss|tt)$/
 (        )   a group
  ll|ss|tt    alternatives with ll ss or tt
           $  followd by an end of string
```

```js
function findingSuffixes() {
    if (/(ll|ss|tt)$/.test(inp.value)) {
        console.log('condition met');
    } else {
        console.log('condition failed');
    }
}

const inp = document.getElementById("inp");
```

```html
<p>Enter a word:</p>
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button onclick="findingSuffixes()">Find out</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar mentions you best use `.some()`

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("inp"),
    sfs = ["ss", "tt", "ll"];



function findingSuffixes() {
  alert(sfs.some(sf => inp.value.endsWith(sf)) ? "Condition met"
                                               : "Condition failed");
}
```

```html
<p>Enter a word:</p>
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button onclick="findingSuffixes()">Find out</button>
```